# Why does my Shotwell app think it is 2012?

Tags: shotwell

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, my Shotwell app seems to think that the time and date is back 1 year, in 2012. I have checked though and my system time/date settings are correct.

Is there any way that I can change this? I was hoping to use Shotwell to import photos that I take on a regular daily basis that I use for my eBay business, and having them in the correct time and date is very helpful.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I take it you're referring to the date and time in the bottom left of Shotwell? This is the date and time of the selected photo.

Comment: @Merri I recommend posting something like that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Shotwell does not display the current time.  In your screenshot, the date/time at the bottom left reflects the timestamp of the selected photo.

If the dates of the photos in Shotwell are incorrect, the first thing you should check is the clock in your camera.  If your camera has the right date but the photos do not, please [file a Shotwell bug](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/) so this can be investigated.

For photos you've already imported, you can edit the times on the photos from within Shotwell.  Just select one or more photos and select Adjust Date and Time from the Photos menu.